# $wpdb->insert() saved data with format. WHY? and how to avoid this?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using wordpress 4.7 and I have some data and want to insert them into my database using the `$wpdb` global but the problem is that the data is saved as it is saved in the e.g. the `wp_post_meta` table, like `s:4:"asdf";`or `s:2:"on";`.
I used this before the exact same way and didn't have this issue. Did something change or am I doing something wrong?

Here is my full code:

```
$table_name=$wpdb->prefix.'products';

$wpdb->insert($table_name,array('name'=>$product_name,'price'=>$product_price,'size'=>$product_size,'status'=>$instore,'shortcode'=>'asdf'),array( '%s', '%d','%s','%s','%s' ));
```

And this is the return value from the database when I read it, so you can see how it's stored in the DB

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[700]
      public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'name' => string 's:4:"asdf";' (length=11)
      public 'price' => string 's:3:"234";' (length=10)
      public 'size' => string 's:2:"on";' (length=9)
      public 'status' => string 'N;' (length=2)
      public 'shortcode' => string 'asdf' (length=4)
```

As you can see I don't get the actual value but the value with the `s:` prefix. I want the values to be stored as plain and without this prefix stuff.

This the `var_dump()` output of my `$_POST`

```
array (size=4)
  'new-product' => string 'yes' (length=3)
  'product-name' => string 'sdf' (length=3)
  'product-price' => string '1' (length=1)
  'product-size' => string 'on' (length=2)

  $product_name=$_POST['product-name'];
    $product_price=$_POST['product-price'];
    if(isset($_POST['product-size'])){
        $product_size=$_POST['product-size'];
    }else{
        $product_size='N';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['instore'])){
        $instore=$_POST['instore'];
    }else{
        $instore='N';
    }
```

Comment: It seems that is not an wordpress issue. You just add them that way. What is the result of `echo $product_name`? As you can see when you add `'shortcode' => 'asdf'` it works.

Comment: echo $product_name;  gives s:4:"asdf"; and btw. I got it directly from the $_POST variable and inserted in into the database.

Comment: Can you show me what you put in `$product_name` ? I mean `$product_name = what you add here?`.

Comment: $product_name=($_POST['product-name']);

Comment: And if you do `var_dump($_POST)`? Can you post the output?

Comment: You can see the var_dump output in my question. The array that u see is the var_dump output

Comment: No. That's the output from database. The output when you're saving the values into database I mean. When you're posting.

Comment: I edited my question and added the var_dump() output at the end

Comment: No. It's a simple WP plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are using `serialize` on your code somewhere which makes to return the values with the variable type like that. Removing that should fix your problem. So if you have:

`$product_name = serialize($_POST['product-name']);`

change it to:

`$product_name = $_POST['product-name'];`

Or if you use it on the whole $_POST like this:

`serialize($_POST)`

remove `serialize()` it and it should work.

Or without having to remove `serialize` just use `unserialize($_POST['product-name'])` just before inserting into database.

Comment: I edited my question again. Loot at the last part and you see how I handled the $_POST variable and sent it directly to the database. no serialization at all.

Comment: That just seems weird to me. From what you posted it should work just fine. There's something you're not showing.

Comment: You got all my code. It's weird to me too. I thought it's something with the new WP version and changes in the API?

Comment: If `$product_name = $_POST['product-name'];` and you echo `$product_name` You should get only the string you added in the input. Try a simple code like `<form action='' method='post'><input type='text' name='product' value='test'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='send'></form>`

Comment: And then on submit try to do an `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){echo $_POST['product']; }`. Do this on a separate file on your server and tell me the output.

Comment: Yes in that case I get the string. But as soon as I throw it into the DB it turns to that weird format. Before the insert statement the values are correct. Maybe the $wpdb->insert does the serialization

Comment: No, that's not the case, you said `echo $product_name; gives s:4:"asdf"; and btw. I got it directly from the $_POST variable`. So the problem is only in that code if it works separately.